# WCF Client hangs when calling Service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a C# WCF Service exposed with these settings (changed some data for privacy issues):

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="TrackingService">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://201.223.147.32:9245/TrackingService"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ITrackingService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name ="SecuredBasic">
      <security mode = "Message"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I'm using the following contract:

```
[ServiceContract, XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface ITrackingService
{
    [OperationContract]
    EquipmentInfo[] GetEqpCollection(string login, string password);
}
```

Of course, the EquipmentInfo struct is decorated with [DataContract] attribute.

When I call this method from a WCF Client, the client just hangs in the last line above:

```
var wcfConn = new TrackingService();
EquipmentInfo[] eqpArray = wcfConn.GetEqpCollection("tr", "service");
```

I'm pretty sure this service is working because other methods are working. The only 2 methods that does not work are the ones that return values. Why does the client freeze when calling the service?

Implementation of ITrackingService:

```
public EquipmentInfo[] GetEqpCollection(string login, string password)
{
    var eqpList = new List<EquipmentInfo>();
    var eqpCol = EqpDataCollection.Instance.GetCopy();
    
    foreach (DataRow eqp in eqpCol.Rows)
    {
        var rowEqp = new EquipmentInfo();
        rowEqp.HostID = (string)eqp["HostID"];
        eqpList.Add(rowEqp);
    }
    return eqpList.ToArray();
}
```

EDIT2:

```
public DataTable GetCopy()
{
    lock (_objSync)
    {
        return Copy();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Have you turned on tracing for your service? That might help you figure this out.

Comment: Can you show us the implementation of `TrackingSerivce`?

Comment: @Jerod, I added the code as requested.

Comment: @RHaguiuda Try start up mutiple project in Visual Studio, so you can set break line in WCF Service to check which line is actually cause problem?

Comment: Thanks for posting that. I'm not spotting anything wrong with your service. Is there anything in the EpqDataCollectoin that might be hanging you. Typically I'd be looking for some kind of reference to the WCF channel. Which I don't see yet.... It might be as simple as being on the wrong thread?

Comment: @Jerod I posted the EqpDataCollection GetCopy method. EqpDataCollection inherits from DataTable. Since this collection is accessed from multiple threads, there's a private object (_objSync) for sincronization in this class.

Answer (score 2):

check the logs by enable tracing on server.

Comment: I enabled Tracing and analised the error.svclog file. I can see that the method is called but this is the last activity in log file. In the detailed activities panel, the last activity is "Activity boundary" - Level Stop. After this, the log is terminated.

Comment: did you try debugging the service by putting break point at start of the method  ? and see which line is the "bone of contention" ?

Answer (score 2):

How big is the `EquipmentInfo[]`? It's possible that the repsonse is too big for WCF's default settings, which causes the server to fail to serialize and send the message. The client, in this case, is left hanging and waiting for a response until the timeout is reached.

Try increasing the message size in the  element, using the maxBufferPoolSize, maxBufferSize and maxReceivedMessageSize attributes. Details are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361.aspx

Comment: Hi, EquipmentInfo is very big. I'll try to increase the buffers and message size.

Answer (score 1):

i would say the client wait/freeeze as long as there is no return from the GetEqpCollection() service call.

i would check 2 things first, what happen if you simply return a empty list. Just to see in client service communication works.

```
public EquipmentInfo[] GetEqpCollection(string login, string password)
{
   return new List<EquipmentInfo>();
}
```

and second i would check the your GetEqpCollection() on server side with a test project. just to be sure it work.